# Unable To Browse or Run Uploaded Project Using IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-publishing

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET MVC web application locally using IIS server. The files of the application are uploaded but whenever I run the application in the browser (localhost/WebApp), get the following exception:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The Request page cannot be accessed becasue the related configuration data for 
the page is invalid.

Module: IIS Web Core
Notification: BeginRequest
Handler: Not yet determined
Error Code: 0x80070005
Config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File: \foo\web.config
Request URL: http://localhost/WEBAPP
Logon Method: Not yet determined
Logon User: Not yet determined

Config Source
-1:
0:
```

I've tried to google and tried to follow this link but seems like need some advice to resolve it: (Clearly unable to understand)

[Troubleshoot IIS Issue](http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7/)

Do I need to configure anything else in the `Web.config` file or in the IIS server?

Comment: please dont like to images, instead include code and exceptions in the question directly

Comment: Please see my updated post. Hope this helps. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't have **Windows Permission** to read the `Web.config` file and I believe, you don't have to change anything in the `Web.config` file.

In IIS server, add a user **IIS_IUSRS** using the security tab in the edit permissions sections. It'll allow all the user to access that file. If you ask about the **IIS_IUSRS**, it means when a web project is run on the IIS server, it associates the application pool with a user like local system, network services. So make sure about it.